# Bring flag dialog in front of flag ack. boxes

Tags: feature-request, flag-dialog

Sometimes there are multiple answers to a question that need flagging.  The 'Thanks...' acknowledgement box that persists after the first flag can float in front of the dialog for the next flag, making that dialog harder to use.

There are obvious work arounds, but it would be a little nicer if the flag dialog was in the foreground.

This is how it can look at the moment:

[image]

Comment: Just out of curiosity, if you were to try and click on the "other" radio button would it dismiss the box or would it leave the box and check the radio button?

Comment: @Daniel - by luck I snapped the screenshot there just as the 'Thanks' box was fading.  Clicking on the 'Thanks..' box dismisses it, the radio button is not checked.